# What is the best way to serialise data when using has_and_belongs_to relationships in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I have an issue I can't solve in Rails 5.

I'm trying to build has_and_belongs_to_many relationships into the code for status in a project management tool. I've called it 'position' as apposed to 'status' as 'status is used in ruby.

Here is the controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

   # GET /projects
  def index
    @projects = Project.all

    render json: @projects
 end

 private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
 end

   # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
 def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :complete, :client_id)
 end
end
```

Heres my models

Positions Model

```
class Position < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :project, join_table: "projects_positions", foreign_key: "brief_id"
   has_and_belongs_to_many :brief, join_table: "briefs_positions", foreign_key: "epic_id"
   has_and_belongs_to_many :feature, join_table: "features_positions", foreign_key: "story_id"
   has_and_belongs_to_many :epic, join_table: "epics_positions", foreign_key: "story_id"
   has_and_belongs_to_many :story, join_table: "stories_positions", foreign_key: "story_id"
end

enter code here
```

And here is the corresponding models

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :briefs
  has_many :features
  has_many :epics
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sector, join_table: "projects_sectors", foreign_key: "project_id"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :position, join_table: "projects_positions", foreign_key: "project_id"
end
```

All the other corresponding models are the same as above, to save space and reading, I've left them off as the error below only corresponds to these models.

The serializer is as follows:

```
class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description
  has_one :client
  has_many :sectors
  has_many :briefs
  has_many :epics
  has_many :positions
end
```

I'm using the has_many in the serializer to output the has_and_belongs_to_many relation. However, I get an undefined method error when I try get all the projects.

The error is below.

```
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `sectors' for # .
```

Comment: change to  has_and_belongs_to_many :sectors, you are using singular version 'sector' which might cause the conflict.